# user control not rendering content of ascx

Tags: c#, user-controls

i thought this was a simple issue until i started searching for answers and realised it's so simple i'm the only one who has it

my user control isnt displaying anything. what am i doing wrong? (besides letting this be my life...)

control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ctrl.ascx.cs" Inherits="proj.UserControls.ctrl" %>

asdjkldasfjasdfljdfasjklasdfjkl
```

use:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="page.aspx.cs" Inherits="proj.Admin.page" %>

<%@ Register assembly="proj" namespace="proj.UserControls" tagprefix="cc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <cc1:ctrl ID="test" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: And what's wrong? No output at all? Empty output (I mean all the wrapper elements are there, but no text inside them)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Change:-

```
<%@ Register assembly="proj" namespace="proj.UserControls" tagprefix="cc1" %>
```

To

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1" TagName="ctrl" Src="/path/to/ctrl.ascx" %>
```

You're missing `TagName`, which represents the text following the colon in the control declaration.  You're also not telling the engine where to find the source file ( `Src` attribute ).  Change `/path/to` to represent the path from root to your control.

Comment: Thank you. That was it. No Src. It turns out the other solution is to drag the ascx page from the solution explorer to the page in design mode and let vs rewrite the declaration. If I wasnt so paranoid about letting vs write code I might've tried that sooner, but I was using vs 2003 the other day and I still get chills...

Answer (score 3):

IF you have created custom control then you should add reference of the dll of your custom control ( from  choose items from ToolBox of Visual Studio). and then Use the following tag in the page :

`<%@ Register assembly="proj" namespace="proj.UserControls" tagprefix="cc1" %>`

If you created User Control then add the following line in your page:

`<%@ Register  src="~/UserControls/ctrl.ascx"  TagName="ctrl" tagprefix="cc1" %>`

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
<%@ Register assembly="proj" namespace="proj.UserControls" tagprefix="cc1" %>
```

use

```
 <%@ Register  src="~/UserControls/ctrl.ascx"  TagName="ctrl" tagprefix="cc1" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you haven't set visible="false" on a panel or div containing your control.

That would've saved me a good hour.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a new user control to an existing project that already contained a lot of them, and wondered why mine was not rendering. Turns out you can also specify this in `Web.config`, under **configuration**, **system.web**, **pages**, like this:

```
<controls>
    <add tagPrefix="cc1" tagName="ctrl" src="~/UserControls/ctrl.ascx" />
```

...which will register the control for the whole project, so you don't have to specify this on every page. Useful for controls that are heavily reused.